# How to update 0th index of array of strings present in react state keeping all other index values unaffected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to modify only 0th index data of an array of strings present in the react state keeping all other values (may or may not be present) same. Can someone please help?

For example:

```
state: {
  key1: value1,
  key2: ["ar1", "ar2"],
},
```

Now, i want to replace "ar1" with "ar3" string with some new value keeping "ar2" same so, the new react state will be

```
state: {
  key1: value1,
  key2: ["ar3", "ar2"],
},
```

Please note array of strings can be empty or undefined initially (i.e key2: null) but I always wanted to add in 0th index
How can this be possible efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for. [ES6 Spread syntax docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```html
// Clone the array for immutability using spread syntax
const updatedArray = [...state.key2]
// Update the first index
updatedArray[0] = newValue;
// Set state to new array
this.setState({ key2: updatedArray})
```